# Babylon syntax error with react native

Tags: react-native, syntax-error, babeljs, babylonjs

I am getting this cryptic looking error in React Native. Tried reinstalling my packages with `npm` and checking my own code syntax, but without any progress.

The console log only refers to this file:
`node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js`

What is the likely cause and how to get more debug info about this error?

```
~/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager ~
Scanning 576 folders for symlinks in /Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules (15ms)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │ 
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │ 
 │  prefer.                                                                   │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/user/ReactNativeProject 

[01/31/2017, 18:22:20] <START> Initializing Packager
[01/31/2017, 18:22:20]         HMR Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[01/31/2017, 18:22:21] <START> Building Haste Map
[01/31/2017, 18:22:21] <END>   Building Haste Map (248ms)
[01/31/2017, 18:22:21] <END>   Initializing Packager (1083ms)
[01/31/2017, 18:22:38] <START> Requesting bundle
                               bundle_url: /index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true
[01/31/2017, 18:22:38] <START> Transforming files
transformed 422/460 (92%)/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4336
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:1)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4333:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1705:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4211:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4031:96)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3947:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3639:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3414:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3394:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3324:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3301:19)
transformed 442/506 (87%)/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4336
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:1)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4333:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1705:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4211:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4031:96)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3947:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3639:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3414:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3394:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3324:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3301:19)
transformed 483/542 (89%)/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4336
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:1)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4333:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1705:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4211:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4031:96)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3947:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3639:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3414:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3394:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3324:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3301:19)
transformed 691/694 (100%)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the `render()` method of one of the React Native components and the use of a spread operator in the wrong place,

```
render(){
    return (
      <View>
        {...this.props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }
```

had to be changed to

```
render(){
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }
```